# Colors print very dark from an HP Officejet Pro 8610

Tags: printing, inkjet-printer

The colors on my print outs from my [HP Officejet Pro 8610](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Officejet-Pro-8610-e-All-in-One-Printer-series/5367603/model/5367606/drivers/) are appearing very dark. It was printing fine a week ago. Levels are near full. I've cleaned the print head the max of 3 times. And I've aligned the print head as well.

[image: photo of print out]

**Update**

[image: generic cartridge]

Not saying that this was it but it may be the cause. It doesn't look like there is any ink anywhere on the cartridge.

There ***is*** black ink on the nozzles of the other cartridges which are all official HP brand.

[image: ink on cartridges]

Comment: Are you using different paper?  HP vs. 3rd party ink?  Cleaning the print head will only help with clogs (missing spots), it won't affect darkness.  Alignment corrects colors not printing in the right location .  The symptom would be offset colored ghosts, which won't affect darkness.  Print mode (draft, normal, high quality) directly affects how much ink is used.  Also, the paper type setting in the printer driver.  The amount of ink is adjusted for the type of paper selected, and the thickness setting affects how much the ink spreads and dries before hitting the paper.

Comment: It's HP ink and the same printer paper

Comment: How long ago was the ink changed?

Comment: Maybe 3 months old?

Comment: do not shot me in the head with this because i will first assume im very very ignorant with printers, but is not there an sponge to clean and if it is full of black ink it will make the rest of colours darker?

Comment: Interesting. There was a generic cartridge in there! I'll post a picture.

Comment: There was ink sitting on the other print cartridges. Added another photo.

Comment: The cartridges in your printer are just ink tanks.  If you're seeing a little ink around where they plug in, that wouldn't have anything to do with how dark it prints.  If you replaced an HP cartridge with an off-brand or refill, that could print differently once the residual HP ink was replaced with the new ink through a little printing.  Other than that, it's likely a driver setting that got accidentally changed.